# Listing data in django admin that not stored in database (and not used standard models for that reason)

Tags: django, django-admin

I got a situation when some part of data stored in database so there is no problems to handle it with django admin. But some data stored in few files on filesystem and i need to parse and show them (no need to have all CRUD operations here, only listing)

I have a way to build custom admin but i prefer to do that with standard django admin. So is there any way where i can list data in django admin that stored not in database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking some inspiraton from Eric Holscher's [recent post](http://ericholscher.com/blog/2010/nov/17/using-haystack-index-non-database-content/), you could create a model just to keep track of some metadata for the files, and use that to list the files in the admin.

```
class ImportedFile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Comment: will get data duplication and bringing difference to syncing db and filesystem but looks like this is easier way that can help